# Issue with synchronization server time on client JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, datetime, client-server

On JSP page I need to display clock with the server time. 
I had tried the following code:

```
function startTime() {
    var timeServer = ('<%= new Date().getTime()%>');
    var timeLocal=new Date();
    var millDiff = timeServer - timeLocal;
    timeLocal.setMilliseconds(timeLocal.getMilliseconds() - millDiff);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = timeLocal;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}
```

But page displays clock of my local machine.

Comment: do you know the timezone of server?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript method will only work the first time its called. Afterwards, since `timeServer` is hardcoded (as far as the client is concerned), your `millDiff` will be wrong in subsequent calls to startTime().  Your value for `timeServer` is hard-coded as far as the client is concerned because JSP scriptlets don't run again client-side, so the value of `<%= new Date().getTime()%>` stays the same each time the Javascript function is called, resulting in a greater difference between `timeServer` and current client time as time goes on.

You should make `millDiff` a global variable, and your `millDiff` should always be the difference in milliseconds from the time that the JSP ran and the time that the Javascript function *first* executed. You should not reset it each time.

```
var m_millDiff = 0;
function startTime() {
    var timeServer = ('<%= new Date().getTime()%>');
    var timeLocal=new Date();
    if(m_millDiff==0)
    {
      m_millDiff = timeServer - timeLocal;
    }
    timeLocal.setMilliseconds(timeLocal.getMilliseconds() - m_millDiff);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = timeLocal;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}
```

Something like this anyway. The code still may not be perfect, but this is the basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using following code

Add a label where ever you want to show the server Time

```
<strong>Server Time&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><label id="timelable"></label>
```

And then add the following java script code at the end of the jsp inside the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
        var jsVar=  <%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()%>;
        var timeZoneOffset=<%=java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())%>;

        jsVar=jsVar+timeZoneOffset;
        function myTimer() {
        jsVar=jsVar+1000;
        var d = new Date(jsVar);
        var t=d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("timelable").innerHTML = t;
}

        </script>
```

Thats it now you will see the server time running in you jsp.